# Health Bar XNA C#

Tags: c#, xna

Here is my code

```
healthBarPosition = new Vector2(0, 550); 
public Texture2D healthGaugeTexture; 
public Texture2D healthBarTexture; 
public Texture2D healthGaugeTexture;

public int maxHealth;
public int currentHealth = 500;
```

In load Method;

```
healthGaugeTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("HealthBar Gauge");
healthBarTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Health Bar");
```

In Draw Method;

```
    spriteBatch.Draw(healthGaugeTexture, healthBarPosition, Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(healthBarTexture, healthBarPosition, Color.White)
```

This Draws Full Health bar within Health Gauge.

I've tried to

```
spriteBatch.Draw(healthBarTexture, healthBarPosition, 
                 new Rectangle((int)healthBarPosition.X, (int)healthBarPosition.Y,
                               currentHealth, healthBarTexture.Width), 
                 Color.White);
```

Or

```
spriteBatch.Draw(healthBarTexture, healthBarPosition, 
                 new Rectangle((int)healthBarPosition.X, (int)healthBarPosition.Y,0,0),
                 Color.White);`
```

When is like this it's just Health Gauge without health bar...bar is somewhere behind gods legs.... xD I do not know where is Source Rectange or where did i set it.

I also tried

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9ldaOGjePE

Same as this video and

```
Maxhealth = healthBarTexture.width;
```

Gives me error, so I removed the comment and it works.

What I want is to draw full health with set health value i.e.: `Current health = 100;` but health bar to be full I can draw with just with Rectangle and problem is that i do now know how to use source rectangle and where to place it

Comment: On a complete aside, this question (with more code, probably) would be a better fit for GameDev Stack Exchange.

Comment: Closer, but you set height and width to 0 instead of position. On the *source* rectangle you want the rectangle to start at the origin of the texture, which is 0,0 and use the desired width and total height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to draw using a *clipping rectangle*.

There are many overloads of `SpriteBatch.Draw` that allow you to set the source and destination rectangle. Heres one: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433987.aspx))

By shrinking the source and destination rectangle, you will give the illusion of a "variable length" health bar. You will likely want to fix the "Left" property, and shrink or grow the "Width" property of each rectangle to get your effect.

When setting up the source rectangle, be careful to set it up so that you are not "off" the texture. To try and explain what I mean when I say a source rectangle can be "off" of the texture, consider the following image:

[image]

The Green rectangle is "Off" of the texture, and is similar to what can happen with the code you posted. The cyan rectangle is what you *want* to happen.

Comment: `spriteBatch.Draw(healthBarTexture, healthBarPosition,new Rectangle((int)healthBarPosition.X,(int)healthBarPosition.Y,currentHealth,healthBarTexture.Height), Color.White);`

this Draws me a Empty bar.
I even set my `currentHealth = 500;` it is sill Empty.
where is mistake?

Comment: @Vladan899 It looks like you are using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433990.aspx) overload of Draw. Your rectangle is setting the *source* rectangle, which with your position offset is likely off the texture. The *source* rectangle should be (0, 0, current health, height) while the *destination* rect would be similar to what you currently have.

Comment: I do not know what you mean ...how do ou mean is Off the texture?

Comment: Thanks....can you fix my code...so i do not have to ask stupid questions xD

Both Bar and gauge use same Position....i do not  know what is source and how to place it on Gauge. Again sorry for asking noobish question...i have truble with this bar for like 2 months.
I used this as example:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9ldaOGjePE   and it still empty.

Comment: Thnx i did set first 2 to 0 priteBatch.Draw(healthBarTexture, healthBarPosition,new Rectangle((int)0,(int)0,currentHealth,health‌​BarTexture.Height), Color.White); and works flawesly now.

Comment: @Vladan899 Great! Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Also You can use [custom effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224977/issue-with-progress-bar-shader-in-xna) for it. I think that is is more efficient and looks more elegant in code ;)

Comment: @Silveor It probably is. I'm no expert on custom effects though, so perhaps you should add it as a different answer.